# groovy XPath with multiple conditions and loops

Tags: loops, xpath, groovy

New guy here.
i need your opinion on this scenario, this is a dynamic unit of measure conversion based on the xml below, the groovy program will calculate the element EachesConversion evaluating every CorrespondingQuantity and Quantity fields.
e.g.  1 XPX = 126 XCS and 1 XCS = 12 EA

Please advice.

```
<QuantityConversion>
  <Quantity unitCode="XCS">1.0</Quantity>
  <CorrespondingQuantity unitCode="EA">12.0</CorrespondingQuantity>
  ***<EachesConversion>12.0</EachesConversion>***
</QuantityConversion>
<QuantityConversion>
  <Quantity unitCode="XPX">1.0</Quantity>
  <CorrespondingQuantity unitCode="XCS">126.0</CorrespondingQuantity>
  ***<EachesConversion>1512</EachesConversion>***
</QuantityConversion>
```

------ this is what I try---
How I use a condition in the find ?

findAll { it.CorrespondingQuantity.@unitCode == 'EA' && it.Quantity.@unitCode == 'XCS' }*.value()

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Comment: What is your question ? Post some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Like @daggett said, [this](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst) has a good example of doing that with a closure.